# I was able to review while blocked!

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, review-suspension

As the title suggests, I am blocked for 7 days for reviewing the posts!

Today when I clicked on the counter for reviews (I don't know the exact name for that), I was able to review the content. I reviewed 2 posts and responded as needed!

Here is the thing: I was able to review even while blocked for being stupid while reviewing!

Was it a bug or something else? It happened just a bit ago.

> [image: recent reviews]

There are the reviews that I did just an hour ago. When I clicked the same link, it reminded me that I am not able to review posts for 3 days more. (7 was the real count!)

> [image: back to being blocked]

I have no idea if this was a bug! Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Indeed, you reviewed [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4239006) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4239005) and neither one was on a post you authored.

Comment: yes, they were from the post that someone else had! I just went to the tab of the reviews and it was just like I was not banned anymore!

Comment: Mods, please suspend me from reviews so I can test.

Comment: review suspension is totally in your mind, like that spoon in Matrix "it is not the spoon that bends, it is only yourself"

Comment: Mods, please suspend LowerClassOverflowian by his petard.

Comment: In general, you may want to crop your images to only show the web page (not the tabs, which may reveal information you'd rather not have the general public know, and what programs or browser extensions you're running or have installed), but that's certainly up to you.

Comment: You're right! I was just in a hurry, as I had to turn off the laptop, I just screen shotted the entire screen and uploaded it here! @Dukeling, I will keep a note on this next time! :) Thanks ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was actually related to the recent outages we've had. The bug was in the review ban check, which was checking for a cached value that was only populated when a user was banned (and we've cleared our caches in the last weeks). I've changed this so the cache is populated from db on a cache-miss. The fix is rolling out with build `2014.3.12.2046` on meta and `2014.3.12.1449` on sites.

Comment: Oh, so the site checks (used to check) for the cache to determine whether he is blocked or not?

Comment: I really hope the post bans are also checked against database, not memory only. :)